# apt-get boost fake package installed

Tags: boost, apt-get

I recently needed to update debian squeeze from boost 1.42 to 1.48. This involved removing the current boost 1.42 packages and installing from subversion the 1.48 packages.

Unfortunately this breaks some Debian dependencies - Is there a way to put an entry into the package manager database to say that boost 1.48 is installed so the system will not try and install the boost 1.42 libraries or is this just very anti-Debian?

Answer (score 1):

There are some packages that help with this, see for example the [equivs](http://packages.debian.org/sid/equivs) package.

But if you have linked-to dependency, I am not sure you can trick your way around this.  Some apps depending on the particular version will just break.

You can usually install several *packaged* Boost versions side by side, see below for 1.40 and 1.42 versions of the serialization library, plus the packages indicating that current development will use 1.42:

```
edd@max:~$ dpkg -l | grep libboost-serialization | cut -c-70
ii  libboost-serialization-dev            1.42.0.1ubuntu1             
ii  libboost-serialization1.40.0          1.40.0-6ubuntu1             
ii  libboost-serialization1.42-dev        1.42.0-4ubuntu2             
ii  libboost-serialization1.42.0          1.42.0-4ubuntu2             
edd@max:~$
```

When I need newer ones, I sometimes 'borrow' the package from a newer Debian release and build them locally.

And the there is of course `/usr/local/lib` where you could always install a local copy before the package management system catches up.

Comment: My backup option is just a local install in /usr/local/lib and just leave the debian 1.42 installed to do it's thing - Rather keen the system neat but might have to go that way - currently experimenting with the testing branch and pinning packages.